# Magento 2: get controller, module, action name in template file?

Tags: module, router, action, name

How can I retrieve controller, module and action name within a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your template extends `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` then you you have access to request via `$this->_request`

Comment: There is a method ```$block->getRequest()```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is

```
$requestOb = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http'); 


echo $requestOb->getModuleName();

echo $requestOb->getActionName(); 

echo $requestOb->getControllerName();
```